# Skip record from one table if record has associatied record in other table

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

How to skip a record if it's associated record is available in other table using sequelize? Don't wana use loop on records.
Example: We have two tables **User** and **Property**, user is associated(has one relation) with Property.
I want to find all those records in **User** table where User record does not have associative data in **Property** table.(i.e User does not have any associative data in **Property** so can't do this Property.user_id = User.id)
I want to achieve this with **Sequelize**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` in query to find out such records, e.g.:

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM property WHERE user_id = u.id
);
```

Another approach is to use `LEFT JOIN`, e.g.:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u LEFT JOIN property p ON u.id = p.user_id
WHERE p.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Can you plaese write that how I can convert this query into sequelize?

Comment: @HassanAjaz http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html

Comment: Sorry Darshan, I need it in sequelize not raw query. And this query is not working in my case. Thanks

Comment: You can probably convert raw query into sequelize? Also, is the query not giving you the expected output or throwing an error?